# How would I get this JSON data to display in HTML in a table showing all the values?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I am trying to display this code in a table format but I am unable to get the student's object to display all of the information in it, I was wondering if the groups object with the array's of each of the student ID's would be able to display the information?

```
var moduleListJSON =
{
"code" : "4COM9051",
"name" : "More Web Scripting",
"cohort" : "IT/JH/ITMB",

"students" : {
    "97xx08xx01": {"firstName": "Jo 1", "lastName": "Bloggs", 
    "allocatedGroup": "690511"},
    "97xx08xx03": {"firstName": "Jo 2", "lastName": "Bloggs", 
    "allocatedGroup": "690511"},
    "97xx08xx02": {"firstName": "Jo 3", "lastName": "Bloggs", 
    "allocatedGroup": "690513"},
    "97xx08xx06": {"firstName": "Joe 1", "lastName": "Bliggs", 
    "allocatedGroup": "690513"},
    "97xx08xx05": {"firstName": "Joe 2", "lastName": "Bliggs", 
    "allocatedGroup": "690511"},
    "97xx08xx04": {"firstName": "Joe 3", "lastName": "Bliggs", 
    "allocatedGroup": "690513"},
},

"groups" : {
    "690511": {
        "name": "Tutorial 1",
        "members" : ["97xx08xx01", "97xx08xx05", "97xx08xx03"]
},
    "690513": {
        "name": "Tutorial 2",
        "members" : ["97xx08xx04", "97xx08xx02", "97xx08xx06"]
}
}

}
```

This is a piece of JSON that I managed to display in a table with object only, however, I'm unable to complete a separate task due to this:

**HTML**

```
function displayParks() {
    console.log('displaying parks header...')
    var parksListHTML = '<table id="parksTable"><thead><tr><th>Student SRN</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Group Allocated</th></tr></thead>'
    for (var parkName in parksListJSON) {
    // store local reference to park being displayed 
        var park = parksListJSON[parkName];
        console.log('  displaying ' + park.displayName);

    // generate HTML table row for park
        var parkHTML = '<tr id="' + parkName + '"><td>' + park.studentSRN + '</td><td>' + park.firstName + '</td><td>' + park.lastName + '</td><td>' + park.allocatedGroup + '</td></tr>' ;
    // console.log('  ' + parkHTML);
    parksListHTML += parkHTML;

    }
    parksListHTML += '</table>';
    console.log('  ' + parksListHTML);
    document.getElementById("parksList").innerHTML=parksListHTML;
}
```

**JSON**

```
var parksListJSON =
{

"StudentOne" :
  {
       "studentSRN": "97xx08xx01", 
       "firstName": "Jo 1",
       "lastName": "Bloggs", 
       "allocatedGroup": "690511"
  },

  "StudentTwo" :
    {
      "studentSRN": "97xx08xx03",
      "firstName": "Jo 2", 
      "lastName": "Bloggs", 
      "allocatedGroup": "690511"
    },

"StudentThree" :
    {
      "studentSRN": "97xx08xx02",
      "firstName": "Jo 3", 
      "lastName": "Bloggs", 
      "allocatedGroup": "690513"
    },

"StudentFour" :
    {
      "studentSRN": "97xx08xx06",
      "firstName": "Joe 1", 
      "lastName": "Bliggs",
      "allocatedGroup": "690513"
    },

"StudentFive" :
    {
      "studentSRN": "97xx08xx05",
      "firstName": "Joe 2", 
      "lastName": "Bliggs", 
      "allocatedGroup": "690511"
    },


"StudentSix" :
    {
      "studentSRN": "97xx08xx07",
      "firstName": "Joe 4", 
      "lastName": "Blaggs", 
      "allocatedGroup": "690511"
    },

"StudentSeven" : 
    {
       "studentSRN": "97xx08xx04",
       "firstName": "Jo 3",
       "lastName": "Bliggs", 
       "allocatedGroup": "690513"
    }
  }
;
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "unable to get the student's object to display all of the information in it"? What is the layout of the table you are unable to display? Is the problem one of table design or coding?

Comment: Apologies for the wording, the problem is with the code, I am trying to display whatever is in the "student" section but don't know how to do so. The layout of the table would be something like the table headers being:

StudentSRN - First Name - Last Name - Group Allocated

Comment: The posted code works and displays student data from `parksListJSON` in a table under the headers you mention within a container with id `parksList`. Make sure you call  `displayParks` after the HTML element with id `parksList` has been created. If there is still a problem, _edit the question_ to include any errors shown on the console and provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue as a stack snippet.

Comment: Yes the code posted works with the parksListJSON. What I am having trouble with is displaying that information with the moduleListJSON instead

Comment: In that case then you'd need to show the code you've written to use that different JSON structure, and explain what exact problem you're having with it. Code which is working, but works on a different set of data, is not really very relevant to the question, tbh.